# Using Ajax to send data to mySQL from modal

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am trying to use ajax to send data to a mySQL server with php but nothing seems to be happening. Is my layout wrong? How would I bind the "submit" button in order so that the data is submitted from the user input of the modal to the mysql database. Would I need the ajax in a different location or would this be fine? I am also confused as to how this binding would take place.

```
<script>
    var cells = document.querySelectorAll('.table-row > td');
    var cellIndex = -1;
        cells.forEach((e, index) => {
        e.addEventListener("click", () => {
            //show modal
        $('.modal').modal("show");
            //update grid
        // This is the row number
        console.log("Row number: ", index)
        cellIndex = index

        var name = $('#name').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var phonenumber = $('#phonenumber').val();

          //store in database
        $.ajax({
          url:"insert.php",
          method:"POST",
          data: {
            name: name,
            email: email,
            phonenumber: phonenumber
          }
        })

  })
})

    function updateTable(e) {
      let name, email, phonenumber, tableRow, row;
      name = document.getElementById("name").value;
      console.log(name, email, phonenumber);
      // Get the row that you want
      row = cells[cellIndex];
      $(row).html(name);
      $('.modal').modal("hide");
    }

document.getElementById("submit-btn").addEventListener("click", updateTable);

  </script>
```

Here is the php code I am using to send data to the database:

```
<?php

  $conn = new mysqli("127.0.0.1","root","password");

  if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }

  if(!empty($_POST))
  {
      $output = '';
      $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["name"]);
      $phonenumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["phonenumber"]);
      $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["email"]);


      $query = "INSERT INTO users(name,phonenumber,email) VALUES('$name',
                '$phonenumber','$email' )";



  }

  echo "Connected successfully";


?>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please post the relevant HTML?

Comment: @WillWalsh Here is the code pen: https://codepen.io/jf451/pen/WNpyvge. I couldn't edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have the `$.ajax` query being run when the table cell is being clicked. It should be run within `updateTable` which is called when the modal submit button is clicked. Remove the `$.ajax` code from where it currently is and change the `updateTable` function as follows :-

```
function updateTable(e) {
  let name, email, phonenumber, tableRow, row;
  name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  phonenumber = document.getElementById("phonenumber").value;
  console.log(name, email, phonenumber);
  // Get the row that you want
  row = cells[cellIndex];
  $(row).html(name);
  $('.modal').modal("hide");

  $.ajax({
    url:"insert.php",
    method:"POST",
    data: {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      phonenumber: phonenumber
    }
  })
}
```

In the PHP code, you are missing the code to run the DB query. Underneath the `$sql` variable assignment, add the following

```
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: Thank you, it is still not showing up in my database, am I not connecting the right way?

Comment: I missed that, but I've updated my answer now.